# Permanent redirect using 301 and .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I had a site in a old domain (http://domain1.com) and I move it to a new one (http://domain2.com) because the site had a good SEO position on `domain1.com` I don't want to loose so I need to keep it and I think in a 301 redirection through `.htaccess` file. This is the line I'd add to `.htacess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /http://domain2.com/
```

But,

> - Is this the right way?
> - Is the line above good?
> - Since I haven't the hosting (files and more) under `domain1.com` should the `.htaccess` file be on `domain2.com` hosting?

Can any clear my doubts around this topics?

Comment: 301 is permanent redirect and some browsers will remember that it is moved to the new location and will redirect without even asking. This sounds like a good solution.

Comment: keep in mind .. that google index URI's not even URL's ... the solution is only the half way ... change every request uri from domain1 to domain2 ...

Comment: @donald123 what you mean by `change every request uri from domain1 to domain2`? You mean at site level or using any `.htaccess` rule?

Comment: yes ... something like RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com$1 [L,R=301,QSA] in .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is good solution. 301 is permanent redirect and is declared in standard HTTP Code. You can use, as you wrote, `.htaccess` file to do that, or configure DNS Servers to autoredirect all queries to this domain (see http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/spry_menu/http-redirection-record/). I think second solution is better, because you don't need to pay for hosting anymore.

Comment: So, if you refer to `don't need to pay for hosting anymore` is because `.htaccess` file for redirection should be on `domain1.com` hosting and not in `domain2.com` hosting, is that right?

Comment: @ReynierPM Yes, that's true